# Writing own logic regression function in R: how to handle ordinal data

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to write my own logistic regression function in R. The goal is to get a function that gives the same results as the glm() function where family = binomial. I have some problems with ordinal data. I tried to factorize it before (as usually done in the case where the glm() function is used). However, the results of my function and of the glm() function are not the same. Does anyone know how to solve the problem with the ordinal data? Thanks in advance :) You can find my code below.

```
manual_logistic_regression = function(X,y,threshold = 1e-10, max_iter = 100)
  #A function to find logistic regression coefficients 
  #Takes three inputs: 
{
  #A function to return p, given X and beta
  #We'll need this function in the iterative section
  calc_p = function(X,beta)
  {
    beta = as.vector(beta)
    return(exp(X%*%beta) / (1+ exp(X%*%beta))) 
  }  

  #### setup bit ####

  #initial guess for beta
  beta = rep(0,ncol(X))

  #initial value bigger than threshold so that we can enter our while loop 
  diff = 10000 # has to be bigger than threshold

  #counter to ensure we're not stuck in an infinite loop
  iter_count = 0

  #### iterative bit ####
  while(diff > threshold ) #tests for convergence
  {
    #calculate probabilities using current estimate of beta
    p = as.vector(calc_p(X,beta)) #p is changing due to the new beta in each iteration

    #calculate matrix of weights W
    W =  diag(p*(1-p)) #varianz von Y, weil Y 1 oder 0 ist

    #calculate the change in beta
    beta_change = solve(t(X)%*%W%*%X) %*% t(X)%*%(y - p) 

    #update beta
    beta = beta + beta_change

    #calculate how much we changed beta by in this iteration 
    #if this is less than threshold, we'll break the while loop 
    diff = sum(beta_change^2) 

    #see if we've hit the maximum number of iterations
    iter_count = iter_count + 1
    if(iter_count > max_iter) {
      stop("Not converging.")
    }
  }

  #make it pretty 
  coef = c("(Intercept)" = beta[1], x1 = beta[2], x2 = beta[3], x3 = beta[4], x4 = beta[5]) 
  return(coef)
}

#I used the following data sample. I want to regress admit on great, gpa and rank.

mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
## view the first few rows of the data
head(mydata)
#
#institutions with a rank of 1 have the highest prestige, while those with a rank of 4 have the lowest.

mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")

summary(mylogit)



rank<- factor(mydata$rank)
rank
class(rank) # make sure that it is really a factor

manual_logistic_regression(cbind(1,mydata$gre, mydata$gpa, rank),mydata$admit)
```

Comment: Looks like you are using x4 as the reference level, whereas R's glm is using x1 (at least among the "rank" vectors). Also looks as though you are only sending 5 model vectors to the function whereas your `glm` call has 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've already tried to only return a list of betas i.e.:

Comment: return(beta) instead of return(coef). However, this did not work either. DO you have any suggestion how I could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, I _did_ suggest that you more carefully examine the models you are comparing, but I'm not clear that you picked up on that hint. I don't think the models being compared are the same. It's possible that you are not treating rank as a categorical variable. The number of columns of "beta" should be more than the number of columns of the dataset. You need n-1 indicator columns for a categorical variable with n levels. If you need ideas look at how the `model.matrix` function does its work.

Comment: Thank a lot, model.matrix()  worked for me! Before giving the x matrix to the function manual_logistic_regression this line did the job for me :   x <- model.matrix(attr(mf, "terms"), data = mf)